# Magento 2.3 - Render billing address in checkout sidebar

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, billing-address

I want to render the billing address inside the checkout sidebar, above the shipping address.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: ok, if you select both addresses then billing address want to show the top of the shipping address, right?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel Yes indeed, inside the checkout sidebar.